# Redux: Notify parent React component when the child component dispatches a Redux action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

My parent component is a React class that has a method in it which does a `setInterval` (amongst other things). This interval is cleared when some conditions are met.

However I want this method on the parent React class to be called once again when one of it's children dispatches a specific action (thereby re-setting the `setInterval`).

How do I notify the parent that the child had dispatched a certain (Redux) action? I'm using `connect` to pass the state down. So the parent and the children share the same dispatch method.

Comment: This sounds like a case where you may want add a property to your state that is updated when the child component dispatches the action.  Your parent component can subscribe to this part of the state using `connect`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that would be the optimal solution for your problem, but how about passing down a callback to the child component and dispatching the redux action from the parent? You would be able to clear the interval there too.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can pass send action method from parent to child, call it in child component like `this.props.someMethodToDispatch()` and do something with it in parent component before you dispatch action.
For example:

```js
const dispatch = (action) => console.info("Action dispatched", action);

class Parent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._handleChildClick = this._handleChildClick.bind(this);
  }
  
  _handleChildClick(action) {
    // You can do something here
    console.info("Child pass action", action);
    // And after that dispatch action
    dispatch(action);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Simulate handle action from child</h2>
        <Child handleClick={this._handleChildClick} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {

  _generateAction() {
    // This is action creator mock
    return {type: "SOME_ACTION", payload: "someting"};
  }

  render() {
    return (<button onClick={() => this.props.handleClick(this._generateAction())}>Click me</button>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```